# SQL Server Consistent Column Encryption

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, encryption

I have a fairly simple SQL Server requirements where I have a column of type `int` and I want to encrypt that column given that the function that will be used to encrypt the column should generate the same value each time it is called.

Context

1. I have system with 2 user roles Source Role, Target Role
2. The Source Role users generate tables with the following structure 
   ID => int
   metadata columns => varchar
3. My system will generate copy of the source table with obfuscated ID
4. The Target role users will have access to the generated table and can add/update the metadata columns however they shouldn't know the clear ID

My Trials

1. I have tried [`ENCRYPTBYKEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) with authenticator and without authenticator however each time I call the function,It generates different value which could be beneficial in some scenarios however mine is not one of them :)
2. Also I have tried using [`ENCRYPTBYASYMKEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186950.aspx) and the same behavior appeared which is different output with each call
3. I have also found this [forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/697b71e4-173f-4966-8345-3d6cf193d659/encrypt-by-key-gives-different-results-every-call-time?forum=sqlsecurity) that is mentioning the SQL Server is using random initialization vector

My question is, What are the possible solutions to achieve my requirements considering that the function will be used to encrypt tables with millions of records.

Comment: What are your *real* requirements? Why the same value? Are you confusing encryption with hashing?  Symmetric encryption that *doesn't* use salting is considered *insecure* and broken by definition. The reason is extremely simple - someone can create a map of encrypted strings and recover the original data with a simple lookup. *Why* do you want identical encryption when you can simply decrypt using the original key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What are the possible solutions to achieve my requirements

There is none.

TLDR;

Modern encryption must satisfy several properties, one of each is [Semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security). Semantic security in layman's terms means that if you have encrypted messages you cannot derive any additional information about the plain text message. You requirements, however, directly contradict this, as by having access to enough cyphered messages, one can derive the meaning of the plain text. This is how German machine Enigma was cracked during 2-nd World War (they reused the key, whereas you want to fix IV. The result is the same though - plain text can be revealed).

For this very purpose [Initialisation Vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) have been invented and must be used.

What shall you do? Well there are two options really:

- Clarify your requirements
- Use a map which does not imply semantic security, e.g. (1 -> 9478, 2 -> 9572, etc). This option is useful if you just trying to obfuscate things like ID, e.g. you don't want to make it obvious how many products a company has for sale.

Comment: Thanks @oleksii for your answer I have added Context section to my question so if you can provide more support :).

Comment: @HossamBarakat are you confusing encryption with hashing?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the note, I agree with you that my situation is more relevant to hashing. I was thinking about creating hash for the input column and keep that values inside mapping table and control the security permissions for that table, What do you think?

Comment: SQL Server has a [HASHBYTES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) function, although the original value can be guessed with a lookup table if there is no salting.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I new bee in the security so can you guide me to the salting best practices and how to secure the salt it selft

Comment: @HossamBarakat, not sure if you need hashing, but the point of salt is not to be un-known or hidden from the attacker. It's OK to know salt. The point of salting is to be different for each record, this prevents rainbow attacks. You can read more about salt [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/why-are-salted-hashes-more-secure).

Comment: Thanks  @Panagiotis kanavos for your support

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write your own encryption functionality to do this, why would you want to do this though, imo could be a security risk

Comment: Would you elaborate more why this could be a security risk ? and regarding my encryption can provide samples, references,... considering the performance requirements

Comment: Any kind of encryption which is creating the same values each time could easily be decrypted by someone else. It depends on what your database is used for, and the potential for someone to break in and expose the data. Google should be able to provide code samples for you

Comment: as far as I understand from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_encryption  that if the user encrypting the data is not the same user decrypting the data (which is my case) then there is no data leakage that could let the user know what is the used algorithm, right ?